# Simple $\chi^2$ test question

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

I have the following question which seems extremely easy, but the way the data are set up is causing me some uncertainty:

[image]

I plan to solve this problem through finding the maximum likelihood estimate for θ=P(a sentence contains at least one Class 1 word), and then performing a Chi-Squared test. This, however, requires interpreting that the data row "# Class I Words" in fact means "# Sentences containing at least one Class I Word."

This is clearly a deviation from what the label in the problem suggests, but it seems that without setting it up in such a way that each sentence can have a (0,1) outcome, a binomial distribution will not work at all. Otherwise, you could have in theory n=5 sentences (as the suggested distribution gives) but x=i≥5 Class I words in total (although this case does not actually arise in the data given). Assuming that we are only counting the number of sentences out of a group of 5 that contains at least one Class I Word does away with this issue and makes the problem workable.

Any suggestions about how this question might be answered without making the assumption I have here would be greatly appreciated. Is my reasoning correct, or is there a different way to answer this question?

Comment: It looks like something (a data file?) was omitted from the question.

Comment: Odd that you can't see it! It is an image of the problem I'm referencing. It appears for me on various browsers and on various computers. In any case, I've uploaded the image here: http://grab.by/smR2

Hope that works!

Comment: I agree that a binomial model makes no sense in this context (in fact I'd use stronger language than that), and that as you suggest, to even make sense of the presentation of the data you require the text to be broken up into pieces in some way. However, for the purposes of answering it as a test question, you put that aside (apart perhaps from a parenthetical comment on the issues), and simply test the hypothesis as given - i.e. 'here's a table of data, test whether it comes from this distribution'; the interpretation of the conclusion may give you some trouble for the reasons you note.

Comment: What you suggested is precisely what I ended up doing. Thanks for your input!